# Maven Build - Eclipse project meta-data error

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to create the meta-data for a eclipse project in maven, but my parter and I keep running into the following error, on both our machines. Ive looked around the forum and have tried related advice such as defining a path in the eclipse.ini file and so on, but this hasn't worked. Has anyone else ran into this error before or can see what I am doing incorrectly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
C:\Users\jheerman\workspace\release\admin-portal>mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclip
se -DdownloadSources=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:jar:2.1-alpha-1 is missi
ng, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-pl
ugin:2.1-alpha-1: Plugin org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1-alpha-1 or one of
 its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:jar:2.1-alpha-1
[WARNING] The POM for org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:jar:2.1-alpha-1 is missi
ng, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-pl
ugin:2.1-alpha-1: Plugin org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1-alpha-1 or one of
 its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:jar:2.1-alpha-1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CTP Admin Portal Services 0.4.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:jar:2.1-alpha-1 is missi
ng, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-pl
ugin:2.1-alpha-1: Plugin org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1-alpha-1 or one of
 its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:jar:2.1-alpha-1
[WARNING] The POM for org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:jar:2.1-alpha-1 is missi
ng, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-pl
ugin:2.1-alpha-1: Plugin org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1-alpha-1 or one of
 its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
org.codeaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:jar:2.1-alpha-1
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-eclipse-plugin:2.8:clean (default-cli) @ ctp-admin-portal ---
[INFO] Deleting file: .project
[INFO] Deleting file: .classpath
[INFO] Deleting file: .wtpmodules
[INFO] Deleting file: .component
[INFO] Deleting file: org.eclipse.wst.common.component
[INFO] Deleting file: org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
[INFO] Deleting file: org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
[INFO] Deleting file: org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.prefs
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-eclipse-plugin:2.8:eclipse (default-cli) @ ctp-admin-portal >>>

[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-eclipse-plugin:2.8:eclipse (default-cli) @ ctp-admin-portal <<<

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-eclipse-plugin:2.8:eclipse (default-cli) @ ctp-admin-portal ---

[INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: C:\Users\jheerman\workspace
[INFO] Adding default classpath container: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAIN
ER
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34.003s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 23 09:42:31 GMT-08:00 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.8
:eclipse (default-cli) on project ctp-admin-portal: Cant canonicalize system pat
h: {0}: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect -> [He
lp 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

Comment: would it help to include a stack trace? also, could it be due to an issue between the software versions I am using? I'm using Maven 3.0.3

Comment: What is the purpose of the "release" directory between the root of your eclipse "workspace" directory and the root of your project directory "admin-portal"? is this a multi module project?

Comment: yes it is, I've successfully made the meta-data for several other projects that admin-portal is dependent upon before this

Comment: [DEBUG] Making relative and fixing separator: { C:\ADMIN_GWT\release\admin-portal, C:\ADMIN_GWT\release\admin-portal\target\classes\C:\ADMIN_GWT\release\admin-portal\src\main\resources\com\cisco\ctp\admin\portal\client, false }.

Comment: that is the last debug line before the crash, I noted that there should possibly be a comma between classes\ and C:\ADMIN, any insights?